I have problem making Vaadin Java app to JAR
I have a problem with a Spring application (based on Vaadin). When I run it with IntelliJ, everything works fine. But, when I try to open the file from the .jar file, the application throws a lot of errors. Disabling the firewall and changing the Java version did not work, and building the jar using Maven did not help. Does anyone have any ideas as to what this mysterious thing might be?
enter image description hereenter image description here
Link to git: https://github.com/SzymonBartkowiak43/howToMakeVadinToJar-.git
Im trying to File->Project Structure -> jar and next build -> build Artifact.
And by maven : mvn package ->  mvn clean package

"delete the file" — What file?

Post text, not images, wherever possible.

sorry, I mixed up words, it should be open

A lot of errors, but you show only one...
Probably your servlet environment is missing something when deployed as a jar file

Your IDE is no build tool. Have you followed the production build instructions for Vaadin with Maven?

have you tried to convert it into zip file before trying to open it?

Please try mvn clean package -Pproduction to get a runnable jar file.
More information here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build
